# filter rows where nan appear in a df column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with lots of rows.

```
             Price   Time     Place
A             5.1    11.30   germany
B             4.1    08.30   lebannon
...
DY            7.49   01.15   italy  
DZ            2.13   02.35   england
```

How could I filter the df to obtain those rows where column `Price` has a `Nan` 
 value?

So far I tried

```
df[~df['Price'].str.isnumeric()]
```

but didn't worked.

The desired output would be something like this:

```
             Price   Time     Place
AS            Nan    11.30   germany
BJ            Nan    08.30   lebannon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [**`isnull`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html)

```
df[df.Price.isnull()]
```

You can also use [**`np.isnan`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html)

```
df[np.isnan(df.Price.values)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
df = df.ix[df.price.isnull(),:]
```

or

```
df = df.loc[df.price.isnull(),:]
```